# Did I win the lotto?

Tags: code-golf, random

I just submitted an answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4665/3862), and then looked about at some news stories about the MegaMillions lottery craze going on right now in the US. [This news article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/record-mega-millions-jackpot-had-gamblers-heading-40-miles-south-of-las-vegas-to-place-bets/2012/03/31/gIQAPUBTmS_story.html) stated that an individual purchased $20,000 worth of tickets at one time (that's 20,000 **sets** of numbers to confirm!) to try and test their luck.

That led me to thinking about how one might quickly determine whether or not they'd won any prize, not just a jackpot, on a large lot of tickets that they had purchased.

The challenge then is this:

### Overview:

Write a function or program that will accept a string of numbers as an argument (STDIN, or read in from a file, your choice), and return the numbers of the tickets with at least the minimum payout awarded.

### Code Details:

- The input will consist of a series of lines, one for each ticket purchased. The winning numbers will be prefixed with a 0, while the drawn numbers will be prefixed with an incremented number starting at 1. (see example)
- The input should be a completely random set of numbers each time, including draws and winning numbers.
- The input should accept any number of tickets *n* where 1 <= *n* <= 20,000. (Assume no 0 ticket runs.)
- Each line of input will have 7 numbers per line. One for the prefix noted above, 5 for the standard balls, and one additional for the 'match' ball. (see **Lotto Details** below)
- The input can be delimited any way you wish (whitespace, semicolon, etc.)
- The output should be a listing of all winning draws and the winning amount. *(So you know which to turn in.)*
- The output listing should be ordered by win amount. *(Who cares if you won $2 on one ticket if you also won $10,000 on another???)*
- When more than one ticket wins the same amount, the order of those tickets is irrelevant.
- The output should also give a listing of the total amount won.

### Lotto Details:

- [Standard rules for the MegaMillions game](http://www.megamillions.com/howto/) will apply, since that's what's so hot right now.
- Draws consist of six numbers from two separate pools of numbers - five different numbers from 1 to 56 and one number (the match ball) from 1 to 46.
- The jackpot is won by matching all six winning numbers in a drawing.
- Awards for non-jackpot wins are awarded as follows (see image below).

  (Main) + (Match) = (Payout)
  5 + 1 = Jackpot
  5 + 0 = $250,000
  4 + 1 = $10,000
  4 + 0 = $150
  3 + 1 = $150
  3 + 0 = $7
  2 + 1 = $10
  1 + 1 = $3
  0 + 1 = $2
- Assume current jackpot is $1,000,000 (one million).
- Assume only one jackpot winner, unless your random draw pulls the same jackpot pick more than once *(are you cheating?)*.
- Assume **no** multiplier/California rules are in-play.

[image: Awarded amounts]

### Challenge Details:

- This is code golf, so shortest code wins.
- In the event of a tie, I'll take the highest upvoted answer. I know this is somewhat subjective, but the main point is still the score.

### Example:

**Input:**

```
0   2   4   23  38  46  23  
1   17  18  22  23  30  40  
2   2   5   24  37  45  23  
3   4   23  38  40  50  9  
4   2   4   23  38  46  17  
5   5   16  32  33  56  46
```

**Output:**

```
4 - $250,000  
3 - $7  
2 - $3  
Total Winnings: $250,010
```

Comment: Can you repeat the lottery rules here? I think questions should be self-contained. And also I can't access gambling sites from work.

Comment: Sure... adding above in a minute!

Comment: Isn't the Jackpot split between all winning tickets?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Fixed.

Comment: No... I win....

Comment: I'm hoping someone else will submit an answer. Perhaps I should extend the deadline?

Comment: Getting to the end. Looks like hallvabo's going to win this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Python, 239 chars

```
import sys
a=map(eval,sys.stdin)
w=lambda x:(0,2,0,3,0,10,7,150,150,1e4,25e4,1e6)[2*len(set(x[1:-1])&set(a[0][1:-1]))+(x[6]==a[0][6])]
s=0
for e in sorted(a[1:],cmp,w,1):
    t=w(e);s+=t
    if t:print e[0],"- $%u"%t
print"Total Winnings: $%u"%s
```

Assuming the input numbers are comma separated.

Comment: Thanks for the math idea: `1e4`, etc. (I should have known it from the start!)

Comment: Do newlines count in python? what about indentation?

Comment: Yes, both counts.
Newlines count as 1 char each.
Indentation can be minimized by interleaving spaces and tabs: 1st level=<space>, 2nd level=<tab>, 3rd level=<tab><space> etc.

Answer (score 2):

## VBA (<strike>660</strike> 535 Chars)

Assuming delimiter is a space (`" "`)...

```vb
Sub a(b)
c=Split(b,vbCr)
Set l=New Collection
Set n=New Collection
d=Split(c(0)," ")
For e=1 To UBound(c)
f=Split(c(e)," ")
p=f(0)
i=1
For g=1 To 5:For h=1 To 5
i=i-(d(g)=f(h))
Next:Next
k=IIf(d(6)=f(6),Choose(i,2,3,10,150,10^4,10^6),Choose(i,0,0,0,7,150,500^2))
If k>0 Then
o=1
For m=1 To l.Count
If k>=l(m) Then l.Add k,p,m:n.Add p,p,m:o=0:m=99999
Next
If o Then l.Add k,p:n.Add p,p
End If
Next
For m=1 To l.Count
r=r & n(m) & ":" & Format(l(m),"$#,##0") & vbCr
q=q+l(m)
Next
MsgBox r & "Total Winnings:" & Format(q,"$#,##0")
End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to significantly reduce the size by converting the `Select Case` into `Choose()`

Comment: Great trick! it's been so many years since I heard of `Choose()`... This is a nice thing to post on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/tips-for-golfing-in-vba

Comment: @w0lf Not a bad idea!

Comment: you can loose quite a few chars by replacing the second to last line with `Debug.?r& "Total Winnings:" &Format(q,"$#,##0")` and removing whitespace in concatenations

Comment: Oh and whenever you have a `For i=1 To 5` or like loop that can be condensed to `For I=1To 5`

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 353 Bytes

```js
(function(t){u={"51":1e6,"50":25e4,"41":1e4,"40":150,"31":150,"30":7,"21":10,"11":3,"01":2},a=t.split('\n'),l=a.length-1,m=a[0].split(' '),w=m.slice(1,6),h=0;for(;l--;){s=a[l+1].split(' '),i=s.slice(1,6).filter(function(n){return!!~w.indexOf(n)}),n=i.length+''+(s[6]==m[6]?1:0),v=u[n];if(v){h+=v;console.log(l+'-$'+v)}}console.log('Total Winnings: $'+h)})("0 2 4 23 38 46 23\n" + "1 17 18 22 23 30 40\n" + "2 2 5 24 37 45 23\n" + "3 4 23 38 40 50 9\n" + "4 2 4 23 38 46 17\n" + "5 5 16 32 33 56 46")
```

ungolfed:

```js
(function (t) {
    u = {
        "51": 1e6,
        "50": 25,
        "41": 1e4,
        "40": 150,
        "31": 150,
        "30": 7,
        "21": 10,
        "11": 3,
        "01": 2
    },
    a = t.split('\n'),
    l = a.length - 1,
    m = a[0].split(' '),
    w = m.slice(1, 6),
    h = 0;
    for (; l--; ) {
        s = a[l + 1].split(' '),
        i = s.slice(1, 6).filter(function (n) { return !! ~w.indexOf(n) }),
        n = i.length + '' + (s[6] == m[6] ? 1 : 0),
        v = u[n];
        if (v) {
            h += v;
            console.log(l + ' - $' + v)
        }
    }
    console.log('Total Winnings: $' + h)
})("0 2 4 23 38 46 23\n" +
"1 17 18 22 23 30 40\n" +
"2 2 5 24 37 45 23\n" +
"3 4 23 38 40 50 9\n" +
"4 2 4 23 38 46 17\n" +
"5 5 16 32 33 56 46")
```

Could probably knock a few chars off that :D

Comment: I see that as 499 characters (with the args at the end of your single line version)... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Gaffi Yes, that's interesting... I wrapped it in a function and "toString().length"ed it, and got 517, but a straight char count comes in at 499... Thanks for pointing that out!